# Calculate the sum of the internal angles of a triangle formed by a meridian, a parallel and the curve x$(u, 2\pi -u)$ on the Torus.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Consider the Torus given by **x**$(u, v)=((r \cos u + a) \cos v, (r \cos u + a) \sin v, r \sin u)$. Calculate the sum of the internal angles of a triangle formed by a meridian, a parallel and the curve **x**$(u, 2\pi -u)$ on the Torus.

Which meridian and parallel do I take?

For a first step, it occurs to me to prove that a meridian and a parallel form an angle of $90°$, this, using the first fundamental form.

[image]

I'm taking $r=1$ and $a=2$, to make the calculations easier, but I can't think of anything.

Comment: Have you calculated the first fundamental form? Do you know how to apply it? If you pick different meridians/parallels, do the angles change?